# Shortest distance from set to point, in $\mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: geometry

Consider the set $\mathcal S \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$

$\mathcal S = \{x|f(x)\le c\}$

where $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$, $c\in\mathbb{R}$, and $f:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}$ is convex (so $\mathcal S$ is a convex set). Say I have a point $\hat x\in\mathbb{R}^n$ that is not in $\mathcal S$. I want to determine a vector $z$ such that $\hat x - z \in \mathcal S$.

I was thinking that the shortest distance vector, with respect to the Euclidean norm in $\mathbb{R}^n$, from $\hat x$ to $\mathcal S$ would yield the "best" $z$ vector, but I'm not sure how to obtain the shortest distance in $n$-dimensions.

I know in two dimensions we just take the derivative of $D(x) = \sqrt{(a-x)^2+(b-f(x))^2}$ and equate it to zero to determine the shortest distance from $(a,b)$ to the curve $y=f(x)$, but how does this generalize to $n$-dimensions?

Comment: Can you give more restrictions on $f$? Your 2d case suggests that it might be differentiable. Is is perhaps polynomial?

Comment: The boundary $\partial S$ of $S$ is the [level set](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Level_set) of $f$ corresponding to the level $c$. The [gradient](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gradient) $\nabla f$ will be orthogonal to that level set. You are looking for $z\in\partial S$ such that $\hat x=z+\lambda\nabla f(z)$. Depending on the exact form of $f$, this may or may not be of use to you.

Answer (score 1):

Consider, as you indicated, the function $h(z)=|\hat{x}-z|^2$. This is a convex function and what you are attempting is to minimize this function on the closed (I assume that your $f$ is also continuous here) convex set ${\mathcal S}$. There is a huge field of research called [convex optimization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_optimization) which deals with exactly this problem, which very important for many applied math problems. If $f$ is also smooth, you can use Lagrange multipliers to find critical points and, then, minima. In general, take a look at the list of methods and references at the wikipedia page above or just google "convex optimization".

Answer (score 0):

We observe that the problem is well defined. As $f$ is convex, then it is continuous; so $S$ is a closed set.  It can be shown that given $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$, $\exists\, \overline{s}\in S$ such that $d(x,\overline{s})=d(x,S)$. Where $$d(x,S):=\text{inf }\lbrace d(x,s)\mid s\in S\rbrace$$ and the metric is the usual metric in $\mathbb{R}^n$.

We thus want to find such $\overline{s}$. We assume $x\in\mathbb{R}^n-S$, otherwise it is straightforward. So we look for the the solution of the following problem:

$$\overline{s}=\text{argmin } \lbrace d(x, s)\mid s\in S\rbrace$$

Consider $Y:=\lbrace y\in S\mid d(x,y) \leq d(x,a)\rbrace$ where $a\in S$. $Y$ is closed because the distance function $d(x,\cdot)$ is continuous, and $Y$ is also bounded; then it is compact ([Heine-Borel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heine%E2%80%93Borel_theorem)). So

$$\overline{s}=\text{argmin } \lbrace d(x, s)\mid s\in Y\rbrace$$

which is again a well posed problem by [Weierstrass Maximum Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extreme_value_theorem), and can be solved (assuming smoothness) with [Lagrange multipliers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_multipliers) (actually [KKT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karush%E2%80%93Kuhn%E2%80%93Tucker_conditions)  but it can be proven that the minimum is achieved on the boundary as mentioned in the comments).

Hope it helped.